# MySQL get two random rows (complex), performance

Tags: mysql, random

I need to get 2 random rows but not just with rand() because it's very bad for performance by 10k+ rows so I got this code from another question here:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM bilder b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM bilder) v
    WHERE rand() <= 5 / cnt
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 2
```

So I get 2 random rows from the table `bilder` and the performance is much better now. But I need to specify it a bit more. I need the rows only where the field `geschlecht` got the value `female` so i tryed:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM bilder b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM bilder) v
    WHERE rand() <= 5 / cnt AND geschlecht = 'female'
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 2
```

But now I sometimes get only one row and sometimes none. How can I do this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have 100 rows in `bilder` but only 10 of those rows have `geschlecht='female'`.

The first query tests its random selection 100 times, and each time it has a 5/100 chance of selecting the row. The odds of picking *no* rows is therefore 0.95<sup>100</sup> (for an explanation why see [the Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)), in other words only 0.5% chance of picking no rows.

The second query tests its random selection only 10 times, and each time it still has 5/100 chance of selecting the row. The odds of picking *no* rows is 0.95<sup>10</sup> which is 59.87% chance!

It would be better if you apply the condition to the count subquery as well:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM bilder b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM bilder WHERE geschlect = 'female') v
    WHERE rand() <= 5 / cnt AND geschlecht = 'female'
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 2
```

Now `cnt` is only 10, and the random chance is therefore 5/10 chance of selecting the row. So the odds of picking no rows is 0.50<sup>10</sup>, or less than 0.1%.

Comment: This is really hard to understand but I'm still gonna try it. It works, thanks!